# Trouble passing the TLS 1.2 check

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I am running CentOS 7 and PHP 7.0.13. I am having trouble getting [TlsCheck.php](https://github.com/paypal/TLS-update/blob/master/php/TlsCheck.php) to return PayPal_Connection_OK. I was running an old version of CURL but I upgraded. I also disabled TLS 1.0 and 1.1. Here is the ouput which includes data on CURL:

```
string(28) "TCP connection reset by peer"
DEBUG INFORMATION:
###########
CURL VERSION:
{
    "version_number": 471808,
    "age": 3,
    "features": 2065309,
    "ssl_version_number": 0,
    "version": "7.51.0",
    "host": "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu",
    "ssl_version": "NSS\/3.21 Basic ECC",
    "libz_version": "1.2.7",
    "protocols": [
        "dict",
        "file",
        "ftp",
        "ftps",
        "gopher",
        "http",
        "https",
        "imap",
        "imaps",
        "ldap",
        "ldaps",
        "pop3",
        "pop3s",
        "rtsp",
        "scp",
        "sftp",
        "smb",
        "smbs",
        "smtp",
        "smtps",
        "telnet",
        "tftp"
    ]
}
```

[SSL Report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=intellipure.com&hideResults=on)

Comment: This is on a VPS with other sites as well, some of which have their own certificates. I'm wondering if I need a dedicated IP address for this site?

Comment: OpenSSL version is: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

Comment: Adding this line to force TLS 1.2 fixes the test scripts: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);  Wondering if there is a way to set that globally and not to a specific curl handle?